# Powershell-CredentialPicker.pickasync($options): Error calling pickasync with 1 argument:"Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"

Tags: .net, powershell

I am running this code from GitHub dviros/CredsLeaker which was working fine until recently now it is giving errors i.e:

```
Exception calling "PickAsync" with "1" argument(s): "Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)"
At line:1 char:1
+ [Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.CredentialPicker]::PickAsync($option ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Exception
```

Comment: The error 0x80070490 is a status code signaling a corrupted file or process in the System Component Store or in Component-Based Servicing (CBS). https://appuals.com/windows-update-error-0x80070490/ re-apply the credentials ?

Comment: @VasilNikolov I ran this on two different systems and what does PowerShell would possibly have to do with Windows Update.

Comment: And I can confirm that this was working in June 2021.